Pavers repositioned
The guys who are installing irrigation in my yard removed the pavers so they can dig and place the pipes there.
They said they would place back the pavers on top of it once the digging is complete. Will the pavers be like original on top of the diggings? I am concerned that with the reposition they become loose.
Thank you

But there is going to be pipe underneath. How can it be tight if there is pipe underneath?

It's one of the main advantages of pavers, that you can remove and reposition them. As long as they add sand and tamp it right, the pavers will look just like before.

add sand That is the key. If, as they are likely to do unless pushed otherwise (and specified in a contract) simply throw the existing dirt back on top and put the pavers down on top of the dirt, they will be loose.

Not sure if you meant "tramp" it down instead of tamp but it works either way.... and yes, sand is a must.

They put back the stone today. It is loose. What should I ask them to do?

Did they add clean sand afterwards, to fill in the joints? If your old pavers had polymeric sand added as "grout", then you should add that too to the new pavers. If the pavers are loose but only move 1mm or so, then you just have to wait for a good rain and normal settling. If the pavers are moving a lot, as in supper wobbly, then they need to be taken out, new sand added and packed, then reset
